# Cross-platform remote desktop with video streaming

Tags: linux, windows-10, remote-desktop, video-conferencing

I'm looking for a remote desktop software with the following features:

- client cross-platform (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 at least), the "server" (my side) should support at least Ubuntu 20.04, Windows is not mandatory
- it should allow at least 2 video streams, one from a USB webcam and one from an IP-camera in addition to the desktop, both with audio layer
- it must have a flag to show or hide the current view on client side. I mean, if I disable this feature, the user that sits in front of the client should not be able to see what I'm doing remotely
- nice to have: an easy way to transfer files between PC, bidirectional copy&paste, chat service

The most common softwares like [Remmina](https://remmina.org/), [Zoho](https://www.zoho.com) seem to lack the additional video streams. It seems that [FlexyHub](https://www.flexihub.com) can do the trick but it requires an external account and it would not be my first choice.

To be clear, I don't want to see the cameras *inside* the remote desktop, but they should be a different streams, so in my local host I can place their windows wherever I want.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [WHIP](https://www.meetecho.com/blog/whip-janus-part-ii/) is helpful?

Available in Debian unstable and testing (and therefore soon in Ubuntu too, I guess) are packages `simple-whip-client`, `simple-whip-server`, `janus`, and `janus-demos`.

1. install and setup `simple-whip-server`, `janus`, and janus-demos` (or nicer looking [Jangouts](https://github.com/jangouts/jangouts) which is not yet in Debian) on a public-facing server.
2. connect to the WHIP service from your web browser, and setup an endpoint linked with a Janus room.
3. connect to the Janus room from your web browser.
4. install `simple-whip-client` on your own or a separate system, and have it enable/disable a WHIP session from your IP camera to the WHIP endpoint, as you need it.

The WHIP client uses GStreamer, so should be possible to capture either an IP camera, a USB webcam, or a screen or window.

The Janus room is accessible from your peers, regardless of operating system.